# uploading photo codeigniter not inserting into the right column

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

i manage to insert the uploaded photo into databases as well as into the specified path, the problem is the photo that i uploaded not inserting to the logging user column instead its create another column, am i missing something? below are my codes and also screenshot in case you guys hardly understand what i meant
[image]

> **MODEL**

```
function create($data){
    $query = $this->db->insert('dosen', $data);
    return $query;
}
```

> **CONTROLLER**

```
public function Upload(){
    $upload = $this->input->post('fotoDsn');
    //Foto Set
    $photoName = gmdate("d-m-y-H-i-s", time()+3600*7).".jpg";
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif||jpg||png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048000';
    $config['file_name'] = $photoName;
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){           
        $upload = 1;
    }
    else{
        $upload = 2;
    }
    if($upload==1){
        $data   = array(
                'foto_dosen'=>$photoName);
        $insert = $this->MDosen->create($data);
        if($insert){
            echo 1;
        }else{
            echo 2;
        }
    }//else kalo gagal
}
```

> **VIEW**

```
<a href="#modalUpload" class="upload waves-effect waves-light modal-trigger" id="<?php echo $result->id ?>"><i class="material-icons tiny">assignment_ind</i>&nbsp;Upload</a>    

<div id="modalUpload" class="modal" style="width: 40%; height: auto">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
             <i class="medium material-icons prefix">assignment_ind</i>
                <h4 class="modal-title"> Upload Foto</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="upload" id="tambahFormUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="file-field input-field">
                        <div class="btn">
                            <span>File</span>
                            <input type="file" name="userfile">
                        </div>
                        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                            <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Simpan</button>
                    </div>  
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

> **JS**

```
$('.upload').click(function(){
        id1 = $(this).attr('id');
    });
    $('#tambahFormUpload').submit(function(e){
        alert(id1);
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url:'Profil/Upload/'+id1,
            data:formData,
            type:'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(data){
                $("#modalUpload").hide();
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do you want it to insert the url into an existing column? or is your issue that its not adding other user details to the newly inserted row?

Comment: yes into an existing column, so i logged in with user ="ragil" the upload photo should be inserted into "ragil" "photo_dosen" column but instead doing that its create another row

Comment: I am not familiar with codeigniter, but it sounds like you want an `->update()` and not an `->insert()`, for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/13895507/689579

Comment: i've been thinking like that too, but the problem is, isn't that update been use if there's already data exist in it?

Comment: Update is used when you want to change/alter **or** add a value to an existing row. So if you want to add (**or** change/alter) the `photo_dosen` column value for the row where `user ="ragil"`, you need to do an update. Resulting query would be `UPDATE ragil SET photo_dosen = "$photoName" WHERE user ="ragil"`. I don't know how that would look using codeigniter syntax.

Comment: thanks man, turns out just another silly question, you're right, it should use  `update` rather than `insert`

Answer (score 0):

based on @Sean comment it is true that instead using `insert`, we should use `update`, so the correct controller will look like this, using `update` model rather than `create` and put parameter on my function, on second though the reason why it's not insert into the correct column because the id of the user can't be found (`where` clause), so with `update` we can set the `where` clause and point it into the `user` `id`, Hope this help

> **CONTROLLER**

```
public function Upload($id){
    $upload = $this->input->post('fotoDsn');
    //Foto Set
    $photoName = gmdate("d-m-y-H-i-s", time()+3600*7).".jpg";
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif||jpg||png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048000';
    $config['file_name'] = $photoName;
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){           
        $upload = 1;
    }
    else{
        $upload = 2;
    }
    if($upload==1){
        $data   = array(
                'foto_dosen'=>$photoName);
        $update = $this->MDosen->update(array('id'=>$id),  $data);
        if($update){
            echo 1;
        }else{
            echo 2;
        }
    }//else kalo gagal
}
```

> **MODEL**

```
function update($cond, $data){
    $this->db->where($cond);
    $query = $this->db->update('dosen', $data);
    return $query;
}
```