# how to insert form data first time and second time update same data?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

code:

```
<?php
    if($this->input->post('submit'))
    {
        $data = array(
                'enq_id'=> $this->input->post('ids'),
                'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
                'follow_up_date' => date('d-m-Y')
                );
        $query = $this->db->insert('enq_process',$data);
        if($query == true)
        {
            echo "<p style='color:green;font-size:12px;text-align:center;'>Your data successfully save.</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p style='color:red;font-size:12px;text-align:center;'>Error!</p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

I have a form having input field name (ids,status) with submit button. Now, I am inserting form data into database now I want that when from data inserting first time then how to update same form data second time ?

Comment: Use  -> update instead of insert. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13895507/1436032

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating records codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895098/updating-records-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

$this->db->insert_id() will return the last inserted rows id, so you can use this id for the next query.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the following way : First check whether the data by its condition is present in your database table. If exists then **update** else **insert** your data

```
if(post request){
    Step 1 : Check whether enqid along with some condtion is already present or not in database table

    Step 2: 
        if (exists) {
            UPDATE
        } else { 
            INSERT
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$q = $this->db->get('enq_process');

   if ( $q->num_rows() > 0 ) 
   {
      $this->db->where('ids',$data['enq_id']);
      $this->db->update('enq_process',$data);
   } else {

      $this->db->insert('enq_process',$data);
   }
```

Comment: My database is blank firstly I want to insert data and then update to a particular row which having common id i.e enq_id.

Comment: u want to add multiple rows?? do you have separate page for insert and update?

Comment: No, I don't have seprate page for insert and update I am doing this using single page.

Comment: so how do you suppose to update? separate button for insert and update?

Comment: you mean when u submit form, u need to update the row if the id already exist in the db?

Answer (score 0):

make new function in same controller

```
public function insert_or_update($table='', $data=array()){
    $seprator=" ";
    $update="";
  foreach ($data as $feild => $value) {
    $update.=$seprator."`$feild`='$value'";
    $seprator=', ';
  }
  $sql = $this->db->insert_string('table', $data) . ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '.$update;
  if($this->db->query($sql)){
    return $this->db->insert_id();
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

and use this function in your controller

```
 if($this->input->post('submit'))
    {
        $data = array(
                'enq_id'=> $this->input->post('ids'),
                'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
                'follow_up_date' => date('d-m-Y')
                );
        $query = $this->insert_or_update('enq_process',$data);
        if($query == true)
        {
            echo "<p style='color:green;font-size:12px;text-align:center;'>Your data successfully save.</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p style='color:red;font-size:12px;text-align:center;'>Error!</p>";
        }
    }
```