# CodeIgniter database creates new entry instead of updating record

Tags: database, codeigniter

So I'm working on a CodeIgniter school project and I got stuck while trying to update the user profile.
Instead of updating the password it creates a new record with the newly updated password.

This is my controller function called "profile"

```
public function profile()
{
    //$data = [];
    helper(['form']);
    $model = new UserModel();

    if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {
        //Validation here
        $rules = [
            'firstname' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
            'lastname' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
        ];


        if ($this->request->getPost('password') != '') {
            $rules['password'] = 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[255]';
            $rules['password_confirm'] = 'matches[password]';
        }

        if (!$this->validate($rules)) {
            $data['validation'] = $this->validator; 
        } else {
        
            $newData = [
                'id_user' => session()->get('id_user'),
                'firstname' => $this->request->getPost('firstname'), 
                'email' => session()->get('email'),
                'lastname' => $this->request->getPost('lastname'),
            ];
            if ($this->request->getPost('password') != '') {
                $newData['password'] = $this->request->getPost('password');
            }
            $model->save($newData);
        

            session()->setFlashdata('success', 'Successfuly Updated');
            return redirect()->to('profile');
        }
    }
    
    $data['user'] = $model->where('id_user', session()->get('id_user'))
        ->first();
    echo view('templates/header', $data);
    echo view('profile');
    echo view('templates/footer');
}
```

This is my Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $allowedFields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'updated_at'];

    protected $beforeInsert = ['beforeInsert'];
    protected $beforeUpdate = ['beforeUpdate'];

    protected function beforeInsert(array $data)
    {
        $data = $this->passwordHash($data);

        return $data;
    }

    protected function beforeUpdate(array $data)
    {
        $data = $this->passwordHash($data);

        return $data;
    }

    protected function passwordHash(array $data)
    {

        if (!isset($data['data']['password']))

        $temp = [];
        $temp = $data['data']['password'];

        $data['data']['password'] = password_hash($temp, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        return $data;
    }
}
```

However I get a registration with the same details as before and the new password.

[image: db entries]

How can I update correctly ?

Comment: It looks like the problem comes from your id_user that is not set in your model when you do a save(...)

Comment: I don't know code igniter maybe you need to load the model from the database and then Have a look there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895098/updating-records-codeigniter

Comment: Where is the `save()` method in your model?

Comment: @SamuelAsor I do that in my controller with  `$model->save($newData);`

Comment: Show the code for the `save()` method in your model. That way, it would be easy to help out.

Answer (score 0):

While updating the user profile you don't need to post password input, just remove it.

Simply you can use the below code.

```
function update_profile()
{
    if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0) {
        $PARAMS = array(
            'id_user' => $this->input->post('id_user'),
            'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
        );
        $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id_user'));
        $reponse = $this->db->update('users', $PARAMS);
    }
}
```

Also, I've updated your code like below, anyway you have to define the update function in your model.

```
public function profile()
{
    //$data = [];
    helper(['form']);
    $model = new UserModel();
    if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {
        //Validation here
        $rules = [
            'firstname' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
            'lastname' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]',
        ];
        if (!$this->validate($rules)) {
            $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
        } else {
            $newData = [
                'id_user' => session()->get('id_user'),
                'firstname' => $this->request->getPost('firstname'),
                'email' => session()->get('email'),
                'lastname' => $this->request->getPost('lastname'),
            ];
            $model->save($newData);
            session()->setFlashdata('success', 'Successfuly Updated');
            return redirect()->to('profile');
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the OP's question correctly. The user might also want to update his/her password in the profile page! Your answer doesn't cover that.

Comment: @SamuelAsor that is correct. I want my users to be able to update name, last name and password.

Comment: @AlexAnghel try this for checking posted value: isset($_REQUEST) or !empty($_REQUEST)

Comment: @AlexAnghel also check your view may your password input has value while posting updated info from your view.