# how to update the data from datatable with modal?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have problem update data in datatable with modal

```
<?php foreach ($requestPermit as $r) { ?>
                               <tr>
                                   <td><?php echo $r->idx; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $r->name; ?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $r->remark; ?></td>
                                   <td> <?php if ($r->approval1 == '1') {
                                            echo '<span class="btn btn-sm btn-success"> Approved</span>';
                                        } else if ($r->approval1 == '2') {
                                            echo '<span class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"> Decline</span>';
                                        } else {
                                            echo '<span class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"> Pending</span>';
                                        } ?>
                                   </td>
                                   <td>
                                       <?php
                                        if ($r->approval1 == '1') {
                                        } elseif ($r->approval1 == '2') {
                                        } else {
                                            echo '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-primary" id="select_app" 
                                         data-idx="' . $r->idx . '"
                                         data-approval1="' . $r->approval1 . '">
                                         <span  class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Approve ?</span>
                                         </a>';
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                   </td>
                               </tr>
                           <?php } ?>
```

[image]

i have the button approval to show the modal & change the value in approval1 field

```
<div class="modal-body text-center">
                   <input type="hidden" name="idx" id="idx" class="form-control">
                   <input type="hidden" name="approval1" id="approval1" class="form-control">
                   <h1>Are you sure to Approve ?</h1>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer bg-purple">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline toastrDefaultSuccess">Approve</button>
               </div>
```

[image]

its my models

```
 function updatePermit($id, $parameter)
{
    $this->db->where('idx', $id);
    return $this->db->update('transaksiPermit', $parameter);
}
```

and my controller

```
function approvalPermission()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('approval1', 'Approval1', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->index();
    } else {
        $parameter = array(
            'approval1' => 1,
        );

        $this->SupervisoryModels->updatePermit($this->input->post('idx'), $parameter);
       
        redirect('SPV/requestPermission/index2');
    }
}
```

i just want to update the field approval1 to value 1, but nothing change. what i missed ?

Comment: you should check whether the input post get posted to the controller, if so I think you can refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895098/updating-records-codeigniter

Comment: its work, just to change in my route